# Rails javascript_include_tag cache with dynamic paths

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, caching, dynamically-generated

I'm using Rails 2.3.5 and I came to the following problem. I have a javascript_include_tag with cache, but I'd like to include some more files dynamically to this include. I can't add another include_tag separated from the original because it'll require the js twice. I'm looking for something like this:

```
<% dynamic_js_files = SOME CODE TO GENERATE LIST OF JS FILES %>
<%= javascript_include_tag 'file1', 'file2', 'file3', dynamic_js_files, :cache => true %>
```

Any ideas?